# Listing modified files using a specific date range in a directory

Tags: command-line, directory, find

I'm trying to figure out a way to list the modified files within a given date range. It is a bit hectic to sniff into each and every folders. I couldn't find a proper guide using a date range but all I could see is going back throwing bunch of static dates or similar.

Please advise if there's a way around to do this using `find`, `grep` or even `ls` arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
find -newerct "1 Sep 2016" ! -newerct "1 Oct 2016"
```

to see all files modified between 1th Sep 2016 to 1th Oct 2016. It works for find version equal or higher than 4.3.3

Here `c` is the inode status change time. You can also use `m` in place of it to have the result consider file modification time only.

Also the time string can be converted to `YYYYMMDD` format. So, `1 Sep 2016` becomes `20160901`.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23508622/1039893

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply! worked like a charm. just to avoid doing a find every, I have just added the path as `find /path/of/the/folder` following with the command... worked pretty well! :)